# Upgrading pinescript 4 to 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm currently trying to rewrite an indicator from pinescript 4 to 5 in order to include it in a strategy that I'm writing. There's a user defined function in it that I'm not sure how to rewrite to v5. The function is below. It works great in v4 but v5 complains of A, M and D being undefined. I believe it happens when it reaches the arrays A[1], M[1], D[1]. I know how to use the ternary expression but don't understand how the logic works in order to fix it.

```
Original code, v4:

calc_abssio( ) =>
    A=iff(close>close[1], nz(A[1])+(close/close[1])-1,nz(A[1]))
    M=iff(close==close[1], nz(M[1])+1.0/osl,nz(M[1]))
    D=iff(close<close[1], nz(D[1])+(close[1]/close)-1,nz(D[1]))
    iff (D+M/2==0, 1, 1-1/(1+(A+M/2)/(D+M/2)))
```

My v5 throws the errors listed below the code block.

```
calc_abssio() =>
    A=close>close[1] ? nz(A[1])+(close/close[1])-1 : nz(A[1])
    M=close==close[1] ? nz(M[1])+1.0/osl : nz(M[1])
    D=close<close[1]? nz(D[1])+(close[1]/close)-1 : nz(D[1])
    D+M/2==0 ? 1 : 1-1/(1+(A+M/2)/(D+M/2))

Errors: 
line 95: Undeclared identifier 'A'
line 96: Undeclared identifier 'M'
line 97: Undeclared identifier 'D'
line 95: Variable 'A' is not found in scope 'calc_abssio', cannot register side effect
```

I'm a seasoned developer but new to pine script. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is **NOT** a Pine Script v4, but pine **v2**, where self-referencing variables were allowed while a variable declaration.

In Pine Script v3 and above, such variables should be declared prior to the self-reference call. Note that the `calc_abssio()` function is also using the **osl** variable from the global scope of the script, which is missing in your snippet:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", precision = 8)

calc_abssio() =>
    osl = 1 // missing variable
    A = 0.0
    A := close>close[1] ? nz(A[1])+(close/close[1])-1 : nz(A[1])
    M = 0.0
    M :=close==close[1] ? nz(M[1])+1.0/osl : nz(M[1])
    D = 0.0
    D :=close<close[1]? nz(D[1])+(close[1]/close)-1 : nz(D[1])
    D+M/2==0 ? 1 : 1-1/(1+(A+M/2.)/(D+M/2.))
    
abssio = calc_abssio()

plot(abssio)
```

See here the migration guide from v2 to v3. The newer versions of Pine use the same logic as the v3. - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed

Comment: I see! Thank you. There was no indication in the original script which version of pine script was used and I assumed v4 by mistake. When I looked in v4 documentation, I couldn't find anything regarding 'self referencing variables'. Not knowing what it was called made it hard to find anything about it. And yes, osl is set as 10 higher up in the script. Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated.